# Height of irregular tetrahedron, center of sphere

Tags: geometry

I know the lengths of all edges of a tetrahedron. How can i connect that with the height of the irregular tetrahedron? 
Is there a relation between the height of tetrahedron and the radius o circumsphere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a tetrahedron is not regular, it does not make sense to talk about *the* heigth, since there are four heights, one for each face. On the other hand, if you know the edge lengths you also know the volume $V$ through the [Cayley-Menger determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html) and the area of any face through Heron's formula, so you know the length of every height. The circumradius $R$ can be found through
$$ R = \frac{\Xi}{6V} $$
where $\Xi$ is the area of a triangle with side lengths $a\cdot a', b\cdot b', c\cdot c'$, with $a\leftrightarrow a',b\leftrightarrow b',c\leftrightarrow c'$ being opposite edges in the tetrahedron.

Comment: But what if the side lengths are not given with coordinates?

Comment: @Mathlearner: I do not understand your question. Side lengths are side lengths, positive numbers, and my answer provides both $V$ and $R$ given such numbers.